# Invalid regexp in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to use this regexp in R:

`\?(?=([^'\\]*(\\.|'([^'\\]*\\.)*[^'\\]*'))*[^']*$)`

I'm escaping like so:

`\\?(?=([^'\\\\]*(\\\\.|'([^'\\\\]*\\\\.)*[^'\\\\]*'))*[^']*$)`

I get an `invalid regexp` error.

Regexpal has no problem with the regex, and I've checked that the interpreted regex in the R error message is the exact same as what I'm using in Regex pal, so I'm sort of at a loss. I don't think the escaping is the problem.

Code:

```
output <- sub("\\?(?=([^'\\\\]*(\\\\.|'([^'\\\\]*\\\\.)*[^'\\\\]*'))*[^']*$)", "!", "This is a test string?")
```

Comment: Just set `T <- 0`  (as might be written by someone setting up a survival analysis simulation), and see what happens. (Then try `TRUE <- 0`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`R` by default uses the `POSIX` (**P**ortable **O**perating **S**ystem **I**nterface) standard of regular expressions (see these  SO posts [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876097/why-and-when-to-use-optional-perl-parameters-in-r),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733416/regex-syntax-changes-between-posix-and-pcre)] and `?regex` [*caveat emptor*: machete-level density ahead]).

Look-ahead (`(?=...)`), look-behind (`(?<=...)`) and their negations (`(?!...)` and `(?<!...)`) are probably the most salient examples of `PCRE`-specific (**P**erl-**C**ompatible **R**egular **E**xpressions) forms, which are not compatible with `POSIX`.

`R` can be trained to understand your regex by activating the `perl` option to `TRUE`; this option is available in all of the `base` regex functions (`gsub`, `grepl`, `regmatches`, etc.):

```r
output <- sub(
  "\\?(?=([^'\\\\]*(\\\\.|'([^'\\\\]*\\\\.)*[^'\\\\]*'))*[^']*$)",
  "!",
  "This is a test string?",
  perl = TRUE
)
```

Of course it looks much less intimidating for R>=4.0 which has raw string support:

```r
output <- sub(
  R"(\?(?=([^'\\]*(\\.|'([^'\\]*\\.)*[^'\\]*'))*[^']*$))",
  "!",
  "This is a test string?",
  perl = TRUE
)
```